# How to stub model method for rspec controller test

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, rspec-rails

I'm trying to stub the model method which I'm using in my controller, but it never seems to be working. Can someone let me know the proper way to do it

**User Controller**

```
 if current_user.user_token
      @user = @account.users.find(params[:id])
      @user.revoke_seat(:admin, current_user)
      render :template => "/admin/users/revoke_seat"
    else
      render :js => "window.location.href='#{server_url}/oauth/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=#{client_id}&state=#{request.referrer}?auto_revoke_seat=true&redirect_uri=#{auth_service_callback_url}";
    end
```

**Rspec**

```
 before do
    users(:admin).stub(:internal_admin?).and_return(true)
    login_as :admin
    user.stub(:user_token).and_return("123123")# THIS IS NOT WORKING
  end

  it "should redirect to authentication service to generate access token" do
      expect(user).to receive(:user_token).and_return(true)
      xhr :put, :revoke_seat, account_id: account.id, id: user.id
      expect(response).to render_template('admin/users/revoke_seat')
      expect(assigns(:account)).to eq(account)
      expect(assigns(:user)).to eq(user)
    end
```

Answer (score 1):

You might try the `allow` approach instead of `stub`. E.g., `allow(:admin).to receive(:internal_admin?).and_return(true)`